# How to use derived tables in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm looking for a way to use nested table expression in Postgres 8.3+

I tried code

```
SELECT * FROM ((select 1) _hind) cc
```

but got error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
>       LINE 7:   ) cc

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using two aliases for the same subquery. Are you doing it for some reason? This is the correct version:

```
SELECT * FROM ( (select 1 ) ) cc
```

Comment: The extra pair of parentheses is just noise and no column alias leads to a default alias.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this (if you want exactly 2 levels of nested `SELECT`s (instead of possible 1 or none)):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM ( SELECT * 
        FROM ( SELECT 1 ) _hind ) cc
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d9c2/1)

*P.S.: Maybe I've misunderstood the question.*